# Connecting a postgresql database, node.js and react.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, postgresql

I created a node.js file:

```
const express = require("express");

const app = express();
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
var dateFormat = require('dateformat');

app.set("port", 3001);

app.use(bodyParser.json({ type: "application/json" }));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

const Pool = require("pg").Pool;
const config = {
    host: "localhost",
    user: "Austin",
    password: "astros5",
    database: "cubing"
};

const pool = new Pool(config);

app.post("/add-time", async (req,res) => {
    const name = req.body.name;
    const time = req.body.time;

    
    const template = 'INSERT INTO times (name,time) VALUES ($1,$2)';
    const response = await pool.query(template, [name,time]);
    

});

app.get("/list", async (req,res) => {
    const template = await pool.query('SELECT * FROM times');
    res.json({times: template.rows});

})

app.get("/", (req,res) => {
    res.json({ message: "We did it!" });
});

app.listen(app.get("port"), () => {
    console.log('Server at: http://localhost:${app.get("port")}/');
});
```

This works opening up a database on my local computer. Now, I want to bring that over to a webpage i built with react.js. I have a util.js file:

```
require("isomorphic-fetch");

function addName(time) {
  return fetch('http://localhost:3001').then(function(resp)
    {
      return resp.json();
    });
}

function handleError(error) {
  console.warn(error);
  return null;
}

module.exports = {
  getInfo: function(time) {
    return addName(time).catch(handleError);
  }
};
```

And in my main index.js file, I added a constructor, `this.state = {name:"..."};`, two methods:

```
  handleUpdate(evt) {
    this.setState({name: evt.target.value});
  }
  
  async handleAddName(evt) {
    const user = await getInfo(this.state.name);
    this.setState({user});
  }
```

And now under render I have:

```
      <p><input type='text' value={this.state.name} onChange={this.handleUpdate.bind(this)} /></p>
      <button className='button-style' onClick={this.handleAddName.bind(this)}>Add Time</button>
```

When I enter anything into the textbox on my main page and then click the button, nothing happens. I'm trying to build this based on a a file we used in one of my classes, but in that class, we only retreived info, we didn't post anything. I'm running my file `node server.js` and `npm run dev`.

Do you see what I'm doing wrong? It doesn't return anything.

Edit: I run npm on http://localhost:3000
Edit1: My util.js file

```
require("isomorphic-fetch");

function addName(time) {
  return fetch('http://localhost:3001/add-time', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
    data: JSON.stringify({name})
  }) 
}

function handleError(error) {
  console.warn(error);
  return null;
}

module.exports = {
  getInfo(name) {
    return addName(name).catch(handleError);
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was more than one issue. I'll post the corrected code with explanations.

```js
// index.js (server)
const express = require("express");
const cors = require("cors")  // install cors
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
var dateFormat = require('dateformat');

const app = express();
app.set("port", 3001);

app.use(cors())
app.use(bodyParser.json({ type: "application/json" }));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

const Pool = require("pg").Pool;
const config = {
    host: "localhost",
    user: "Austin",
    password: "astros5",
    database: "cubing"
};

const pool = new Pool(config);

app.post("/add-time", async (req, res) => {
    const name = req.body.name;
    const time = req.body.time;
    // It would be better to set the time server-side
    const timeStamp = dateFormat(time, dateFormat.masks.isoDateTime)

    const template = 'INSERT INTO times(name, time) VALUES($1, $2)'
    const response = await pool.query(template, [name, timeStamp])

    res.end()
});

app.get("/list", async (req, res) => {
    const template = await pool.query('SELECT * FROM times');
    res.json({ times: template.rows });

})

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.json({ message: "We did it!" });
});

app.listen(app.get("port"), () => {
    console.log(`Server at: http://localhost:${app.get("port")}/`);
});
```

```js
// App.js (client)
import React from 'react';
import { addName } from "./utils";

// I'm using hooks... That just avoids `this`
function App() {
  const [name, setName] = React.useState("")

  function handleUpdate(evt) {
    setName(evt.target.value);
  }

  // I assume you want to add the name with a timestamp.
  // There were name and time names confused.
  async function handleAddName(evt) {
    await addName(name);
  }

  return <div>
    <p><input type='text' value={name} onChange={handleUpdate} /></p>
    <button className='button-style' onClick={handleAddName}>Add Name</button>
  </div>
}

export default App;
```

```js
// utils.js (client)
import "isomorphic-fetch"

export function addName(name) {
    // This is how to do a POST request. 
    // Note: Never trust your client. Better to set time on the server.
    return fetch('http://localhost:3001/add-time', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
        body: JSON.stringify({ name, time: Date.now() })
    })
}
```

Comment: Am i adding this to my util.js?

Comment: Sorry that I forgot context... This should replace the `fetch` call in your `addName` function.

Comment: I'm still having the issue of it not resulting in anything when I click the button, so I'm assuming there is a connection issue. If i enter 'SELECT * FROM times' it only returns what I manually put in. Does the util.js file I have above look correct or am I missing something? It's the last thing on the page

Comment: I've added the full working example. There are comments explaining what went wrong.

Comment: Alright, I appreciate it. My index.js is set up as the homepage, using react, and server.js is the node file. Am i able to call the App.js and util.js you have above? I'm trying to call what you have in App.js from render

Comment: Just use it like any React component: `<App />`